# Save Range to dictionary with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have an excel sheet with the following rows and columns. I will like to save this into a dictionary so that i can use the year in column A as the key to reference each rows and then add row values with same year in column A.

Please how can I get this done since am stuck on this code. Thanks

```
A  ....|.. B..| ..C..|..D.                                                                            
 2014  | UNION| 5677 | 4556                  
 2014  | UNION| 5677 | 4556                
 2015  | BEST | 5677 | 4556              
 2015  | BEST | 5677 | 4556
```

Here is my codes.

```
Sub AnyThing()
Dim lastrow_DE As Integer

lastrow_DE = DEsheet.Cells(DEsheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

DEsheet.Range("A1:L" & lastrow_DE).Select

Selection.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("UNION", "BEST"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Selection.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("2014", "2015"), Operator:=xlFilterValues


Dim rng As Range

Set rng = DEsheet.Range("A2:L" & lastrow_DE).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


Dim p As Variant

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary


For Each p In rng

dict.Add key = p.Items(1).Value, items =p.Items(2).Value, p.Items(3).Value, p.Items(4).Value

Next

Else

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show the expected output for the above please? And the data shown doesn't seem to entirely match with code unless there are two sheets. I can't see a text field with "UNI", "IND"

Comment: And is there a reason you want vba rather than a formula (if a formula solution is possible) ?

Comment: I do not find where the `IF` statement started.

Comment: Where does UNI and IND come into this? It doesn't appear in the data sample. And with the sample given would 2014 be 25071?

Comment: Ok. Would your dictionary have keys 2014 and 2015 with Items 20466 respectively?

Comment: You will only have two entries in your dictionary. Your keys will be `True` and `False`. That's because you are setting the `key` value with `key = p.Items(1).Value` (and you're never actually setting `key` in the first place). So unless that's your intent, don't use a boolean operator `=` as an input parameter.

Comment: so you want to overwrite (erase the previous) value stored for 2014 with the next row's data (that also starts with 2014)?

Comment: They won't have any dictionary entries as the filter will leave no cells visible and code will error. Which it would even if it did compile, which it won't.

Comment: It has everything to do with the filter. Wrong filter = no values = no dictionary populated. See answer below for starting point.

Comment: @QHarr ...yes a dictionary of dictionary i can then copy its values for each unique keys (2014, 2015) to an excel sheet

Comment: I am guessing there is a rep limit. It is probably about 10-15 so you are not far off.

Comment: I am confused by what you asking. Let me review.

Comment: This code produces one row per combination of year and Union|Best. The individual subtotals for these combinations are give starting from column E.

Comment: You would better off mocking up some sample data in a spreadsheet and the expected result and posting an image of that as link here. I'm a visual learner in many regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run something like the code below. You might use a dictionary of dictionaries. I have chosen to create a key which is the concantenation of yearn and your second filter value and then split this out after when writing back to sheet.

Note I have changed your second criteria field to one as you show year as being in column A.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AnyThing()
    Dim lastrow_DE As Long
    Dim DEsheet As Worksheet
    Set DEsheet = ActiveSheet

    lastrow_DE = DEsheet.Cells(DEsheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    With DEsheet.Range("A1:L" & lastrow_DE)
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("UNION", "BEST"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("2014", "2015"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

    Dim rng As Range, p As Variant, dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    '<== You should add a test here that filter columns contain filter values i.e. there will be visible cells after applying filter
    Set rng = DEsheet.Range("A2:L" & lastrow_DE).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each p In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        If Not dict.Exists(p.Value & "," & p.Offset(, 1)) Then
            dict.Add p.Value & "," & p.Offset(, 1), Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(p.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 10))
        Else
            dict(p.Value & "," & p.Offset(, 1)) = dict(p.Value & "," & p.Offset(, 1)) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(p.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 10))
        End If
    Next p

    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print key & " : " & dict(key)
    Next key

    Sheets.Add

    Dim counter As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each key In dict.Keys
            counter = counter + 1
            .Cells(counter, "A").Resize(1, 2) = Split(key, ",")
            .Cells(counter, "C") = dict(key)

        Next key
    End With

End Sub
```

---

**Data:**

[image: Data]

---

**Output:**

Immediate window

[image: Immediate window output]

Sheet output

### [image: Sheet]

Comment: There are far less columns in this. Are there just the 4 columns? And are they A:D? P.S. Thank you for tidying up comments. +1 for working hard on this.

Comment: @jitjagboro see my comment above.

Comment: The problem is. you want me to sum column C separately from column D  right? It becomes more complex if we are then saying you actually want col C,D,E,F,G summed separately. It is better to give me a full example to work with please.

Comment: I will review after work. Please remember to include expected result.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Click Expected result]
.....
[image: Click raw data]

Column E is Year and date (to be used as dict key) ...Column C is equivalent to best and union column... G,H,I,J,L sums column with similar "year and date + similar column C" ... I am using a dictionary because I can add the data together by running the VBA as more data is added @QHarr

[image: QHarr .. fake data]

Comment: The data is already sorted. So you will see no difference with a sort applied. And yes, of course, I will give more explanation for you :-) Is tomorrow ok for adding the explanation document?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5ZFgU5sT for sort code. I didn't need to copy the visible rows because I did the opposite earlier. I deleted the hidden rows. So only the rows of interest were left in the sheet. I did this because visible rows may not be contiguous and I needed a contiguous range to work with.

Comment: The code creates that sheet and deletes it after. It’s where all the real work is done.

Comment: It uses the new sheet and sumifs referring to the original source sheet to calculate the totals. The conditions for the sumif come from column 1 and 4 of the new sheet I.e. the filtered rows by item e.g. qharr and yearMonth (20170301)

Comment: I will write explanation tomorrow. For now, here is a file you can use by itself to understand what is going on, or at least watch it. Arrange your Excel VBE (code area) on the left half of screen and Excel worksheet on right half of screen and then press F8 to step through the code line by line. Watch the right hand side of the screen to see the changes in the sheet. https://ufile.io/gd23j

Comment: https://ufile.io/r0l80 Side by side view to use with file I just gave you and for SUMIFs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-sumifs-method-excel